# (Error: valueOf(Class<T>, String) of type Enum<E> but does not hide it) Upgrade version from jdk1.6 to jdk1.7

Tags: java, enums

When I have upgrade java version from jdk1.6 to jdk1.7 in eclipse, The below error has started to throw in compile mode only.

The error is:

> Name clash: The method valueOf(Class, String) of type TestEnum has the same erasure as valueOf(Class, String) of type Enum but does not hide it

```
public enum TestEnum {
    ABC;
    public static TestEnum valueOf(Class<TestEnum> enumType, String value){//This error throw at this line.
        return null;

    };

}
```

When I have changed compile level from 1.7 to 1.6, error has gone. 
I do't understand why is this not working with compile level 1.7? is there any other changes need to compile level 1.7?

**Edit:**

It returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the specified name. The name must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type. but I have not such case, the name is different.There are above 100 enum classes which has same implementation. it is not easy for me to change such product wide change.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    ABC;
    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
        case ABC:
            return "Abc";
        }
        return "";
    }
/*  public static TestEnum valueOf(Class<TestEnum> enumType, String value){
        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ")){
            return ABC;
        }
        return null;

    };*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEnum t=TestEnum.valueOf(TestEnum.class,"Abc");
        System.out.println(t);

    }

}
```

> >
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.test.example.TestEnum.Abc
>       at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
>       at com.test.example.TestEnum.main(TestEnum.java:22)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `static <T extends Enum<T>> T Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` is not the same as your `public static TestEnum valueOf(Class<TestEnum> enumType, String value)`, but look the same after type erasure (both essentially become static Object valueOf(Class enumType, String value).

Since this can lead to unintuitive behavior, the Java creators decided that this should be an error; the corresponding check was implemented in Java 1.7. If your `valueOf` method behaves (or should behave) like `Enum.valueOf`, you can simply remove it. Otherwise, renaming it could solve the problem.

Comment: It returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the specified name.  The name must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type. but I have not such case, the name is different.There are above **100 enum** classes which has same implementation. it is not easy for me to change such product wide change.

Comment: From your comment I gather that the valueOf-Methods behave exactly as intended, and thus could safely be removed without breaking source compatibility.  I would use a sed-script or other means of project-global search and replace and replace `static ([\w\d_]*) valueOf(Class<\1>` with `@Deprecated private static \1 _valueOf(Class<\1>`.