# How can I Refactor enum class valueof method?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

When I have upgrade java version from 1.6 to 1.7, it is started to throw that mention in this SO Question
[(Error: valueOf(Class<T>, String) of type Enum<E> but does not hide it) Upgrade version from jdk1.6 to jdk1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29139643/1427460)

There is only 1 way which I know to refactor 1 by 1 method through Altr+shift+r or Right click method->Refactor->Rename.
But There are more than 100 method enum classes that having valueOf method. 
It is also possible through regular expression also. but I don't have much idea about it.
Is there any one can help me?

Suppose I have this class

```
public enum ActionStatus implements IsSerializable, Serializable {

    NOT_STARTED, STARTED;

    public String toString() {
        switch(this) {
            case NOT_STARTED: 
                return "Not Started";
            case STARTED: 
                return "In Progress";
        }

        return null;
    };
    public static ActionStatus valueOf(Class<ActionStatus> enumType, String value){ //I want to refactor this method

            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(NOT_STARTED.toString()))
                return ActionStatus.NOT_STARTED;
            else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(STARTED.toString()))
                return ActionStatus.STARTED;
            else 
                return null;
    }   
}
```

**Edit:**
it's toString value different than constant name.

1. In combo ( UI widget), it shows toString value. when user select the value, it get enum constant through valueOf method for storing in database.
2. Some of places comma separate enum value store in database, so it's store toString value with comma in database.
   After fetching, it split and to value of it and return list of constant enum and used in code function.

If I don't override valueof method, it will try to compare same constant value and don't find equality. So It break so many features in product.

Comment: Why did you write your own valueOf method when that already exists?

Comment: Are you aware of this method? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: @immibis because it's toString value different than constant name. I have edited. let me know if u have any query

Answer (score 0):

Apart from "this is a very bad practice", just remove "Class enumType, " maybe? You never use it anyway and methods will became different.

So, Find And Replace... > "`Class<ActionStatus> enumType,` "->""

But you'll still have to change calls manually. They will be marked errors, though.